# provisioning download button gray

Tags: ios, provisioning

In my "IOS provisioning portal", I cannot download the "Development Provisioning Profiles", all the download buttons are gray out. it used to work well.

Anyone know possible reasons?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Might be your subscription has expired. Otherwise, you might need to renew the profile.

Comment: ah, my Certificate is gone, dont know why...

Answer (score 0):

my certificate is gone, dont know why. Anyway, after I request a new certificate, all the buttons became normal.